# How can I get my hands on McKay's "Finite p-Groups" lecture notes?

Tags: reference-request, finite-groups, p-groups

The notes I'm talking about are [these](http://www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/~pjc/qmmn/vol18.html).

I emailed Peter Cameron, but he has since moved to a different university, and has no copies himself.  I also emailed the school manager at Queen Mary, but they have no physical copies either.  I can't seem to find this in any [university library](http://www.worldcat.org/title/finite-p-groups/oclc/249431665) near where I live, nor can I find it available (used) on any popular [book sites](http://www.addall.com/New/submitNew.cgi?query=9780902480179&type=ISBN&location=10000&state=PA&dispCurr=USD).

Comment: I have a copy I photocopied from *somewhere*... can’t remember where. But I remember running into the same issue with Queen Mary when attempting to get a copy of Hall’s book on $p$-groups.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: I remember I had the same issue with Hall's book, but was able to find a used copy on Alibris (I think).  No such luck with McKay's book.  What's the etiquette on asking about that photocopy? Or if you can remember what library you used, I can try an inter-library loan.

Comment: Using FirstSearch/Worldcat (link from my home institution), I find copies at UC Berkeley, Notre Dame, Minnesota-Minneapolis, Cornell, Brown, Wisconsin Madison (General library), The College of New Jersey, Illinois at Urbana-Champaign, and University of Oklahoma (Bizzell Memorial Stacks).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: I saw these on WorldCat as well (I linked in my question), but they all say "Book not held"?

Comment: If I follow up on some of the links (under “1 other format”) you can get to the “local” library catalog; doing so, I get information; for example, following through to University of Oklahoma, it says “Policy: sign in for loan period.” Wisconsin says you can request the item (but you have to log in), etc. I don’t know what “Book not held” means in WorldCat, but it looks like the physical book is available in the corresponding libraries...

Comment: I was able to borrow this through a local university. Too bad I couldn't purchase it anywhere!